# iPhone interface design and deployment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, flash, animation

What are the best iPhone user interface applications out there? Are there any with similar capabilities to flash (i.e. the ability to animate page transitions, fade in/out objects etc)

Comment: Test some top games from app store. You will realize what (at least) can be done.

Answer (score 1):

There are many iPhone apps which present ravishing GUI, from productivity apps to games.
Animating page(view) transitions, fade in/out, animating a GUI componenet to move, fade, jump, pop, etc is very simple and possible in the basic SDK, using simple commands such as:

```
someObject.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 60);//sets the object size
[UIView beginAnimations:@"someAnimation" context:nil];//begin stacking animation instructions
          [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
          [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.1];
          [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
          [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:someObject.view cache:YES];// for example...
          someObject.view.frame = CGRectOffset(someObject.view.frame, -320, 0);//will animate the object to move 320 px to the left..
[UIView commitAnimations];//animation will start now, is cancelable etc..
```

Using a library named QuartzCore also allows adding effects to layers: each layer may apply to one or more GUI element (grouping allowed): dynamic drop down shadow, gradient overlays, masking, border outlines, and more.. alpha channel for every and any component is native.
Many of these effects are animation-able as well.

Many games on iOs use OpenGL ES, a 2d/3d engine, similar to MS's directX, but lighter.

iPhone, i guess, lacks the heavy, fast and furious way flash manages vector graphics, with all the curves, gradients, symbols and shapes that are so light in memory and data-efficient. Vector graphics do exist, but not as prominently as it comes in flash.

Answer (score 0):

Flipboard would be the best example for a neat user interface with animations. They have done it very proper.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Design Award winners are always a good start. Check out [the winners from 2010](http://developer.apple.com/wwdc/ada/ada2010winners.html).